# Adjusting distance of blended objects to start and end points in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

I am trying to create a row of houses along a curved patch using the blend tool.

What ruins the design though is the fact, that Illustrator is putting the first and second and last and second to last houses (highlighted by a red rectangle) closer to each other than the rest of the blended object are. 
Why is that so and how do I change mentioned spacing to match the rest of the blended objects?
[image: Here's a picture of the situation]

Answer (score 1):

With your blend selected double-click blend icon in tool panels and select specified distance.